# How to resolve this error when using OpenQuery in SQL Server to extract data from an Informix database

Tags: sql-server, informix, openquery

We are able to extract data from the Informix database as long as the pull is working on recent data, for example:

```
 FROM OPENQUERY (uccx_node1, 'SELECT * FROM contactcalldetail WHERE extend ( startdatetime, year to minute ) - 5 units hour > DATE(CURRENT)-1 AND extend ( startdatetime, year to minute ) -5 units hour < DATE(CURRENT)')
```

The challenge I'm having is getting data that was missed for whatever reason - I need to specify a date range and based on research here and other places, came up with this:

```
FROM OPENQUERY (uccx_node1, ''SELECT * FROM contactcalldetail WHERE extend ( startdatetime, year to minute ) - 5 units hour > ''''' + convert(varchar, @fromdt, 121) + ''''' AND extend ( startdatetime, year to minute ) -5 units hour < ''''' + convert(varchar, @EndDate, 121) + ''''' '')'
EXEC(@query)
```

These are the variables:

```
DECLARE @fromdt DATETIME = '2024-02-20 00:00:01.001';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2024-02-20 23:59:59.999';
```

When I run this, I get an error:

> [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]  > [Informix]Extra characters at the end of a datetime or interval

The SQL looks fine to me:

> An error occurred while preparing the query " SELECT * FROM contactcalldetail WHERE extend ( startdatetime, year to minute ) - 5 units hour > '2024-02-20 00:00:01.000' AND extend ( startdatetime, year to minute ) -5 units hour < '2024-02-21 00:00:00.000' " for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "uccx_node1".

Comment: Don't think infomix supports the `.seconds` part of date, try to remove them. And it's always a good start to debug the query directly on the infomix server first

Comment: Not quite sure you want to do there, and I think it could be simple using a linked tables, but if you want to use that OPENQUERY, try adding a cast for the DATETIME parameters so the SQL query it send to the Informix server will look like `SELECT * FROM contactcalldetail WHERE extend ( startdatetime, year to minute ) - 5 units hour > '2024-02-20 00:00:01.000'::datetime year to fraction(3) AND extend ( startdatetime, year to minute ) -5 units hour < '2024-02-21 00:00:00.000'::datetime year to fraction(3) ;`